# Should I write "If..., I would" or "If..., I will"?

Tags: tense, sentence-structure

> **If** there's a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I **would** choose English.

I know that I can break this sentence down to smaller and simpler sentences like "In some situations, I have the choice to speak English or Arabic. And I prefer speaking English" but I would like to use this long sentence that contains the conditional IF and the word either.

I think the rules are: "If(present), (future, will)" or "If (past), (would)". Now, I used present tense and then I feel it's better to use (would) instead of (will) but I don't know why?

Comment: What makes you think it might not be correct?

Comment: @ColleenV because I'm not that good in English and I'm not used to form long sentences. I think the rules is: If(present), (future, will). Or If (past), (would). Now, I used present tense and then I felt it's better to use (would) instead of (will) but Idk why?

Comment: I edited your question to include that information. If you don't explain a specific concern you have about your sentence, your question might get closed as "proof-reading", which is off-topic here. There is some good advice for writing questions in the [Please, everyone… details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/465/) post.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you so much, BTW, I did not intent to ask a proof reading so I'm glad that I was able to form a long correct sentence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's correct is going to depend on the context.  Here are some possibilities:

**Hypothetical**  *(it hasn't happened, but it might happen in the future)*

- If there **were** a situation where I could speak English or Arabic, I **would choose** English.

**Habitual past**  *(it has actually happened often in the past)*

- If there **was** a situation where I could speak English or Arabic, I **chose** English.

**Habitual present**  *(it actually happens often at present)*

- If there **is** a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I **choose** English.

**Hypothetical future**  *(it might happen in the future; a bit more likely than Hypothetical above)*

- If there **should be** a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I **will choose** English.

*or*

- **Should** there **be** a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I **will choose** English.

Comment: These are the traditionally grammatical answers, but I'll also point out that colloquially a lot of these rules are relaxed in many dialects. In particular, the use of "should be" in the hypothetical future is (in my experience) much more likely to be in formal writing rather than informal speech — I find that the use of "should be" is often replaced with the simple present for approximately the same meaning, even if traditionally considered less grammatically correct.

Comment: Perhaps, but consider that an English learner using these constructions in _speech_ might be thought merely to be overly formal (though it's debatable), whereas an English learner using more colloquial forms in _writing_ would simply be wrong.  Better to learn the standard forms first.  First one learns the rule; then one learns when and where to break it.

Comment: I've never seen that first hypothetical future form ("If there should be...") actually used; I've only ever seen people say something of the form: "If there is a situation [that happens sometime in the future], I will [do something]." The other sentences seem right to me, though.

Comment: There could possibly also be a hypothetical "If there is", to refer to a situation that currently exists, but that the speaker hasn't gotten to yet (I'm not sure if that makes sense).

Comment: @V2Blast The first sentence is the English subjunctive.  It's used in a case like this when describing a condition contrary to fact: *If there were such a situation (but there hasn't been)...*

Comment: @Kyralessa: I was talking about the "hypothetical future form" you mentioned at the end of your answer. I know how the regular subjunctive works.

Comment: @Kyralessa agreed. I just thought it was a comment worth making :)

Comment: @V2Blast Oh, sorry about that; I didn't read very carefully.  Between those two "hypothetical future" sentences I prefer the second anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Your long sentence is correct

> **If** there's a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I **would** choose English.

also

> *(future, future)*
>   **If** there ***will be*** a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I ***will*** choose English.
>
> *(present, future)*
>   **If** there ***is*** a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I ***will*** choose English.
>   *(future, future)*
>   **If** there ***is*** a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I ***would*** choose English.
>
> *(past, past)*
>   **If** there ***was*** a situation where I can speak either English or Arabic, I ***would*** choose English.

Comment: I'm inclined to say "where I could speak" should go with "I would choose" (to refer a hypothetical) and "where I can speak" should go with "I choose" (to refer to a habitual present). It's "If I could, I would", not "If I can, I would".